# `LEDGER_MAX_TX_SIZE` and `5` seconds `EXP_LEDGER_TIMESPAN_SECONDS` gives only `20` tx per second?

Tags: consensus, ledger, speed

It seems like the consensus nomination period is set to `5` seconds and each ledger size is maximized at `100` transactions per ledger, so that would give `20` transactions per second at best.

Am I understanding this wrong? That seems too slow to be true and official dev doc does claim thousands of transactions per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations are correct, insofar as this is the only way to successfully transact using a single account without risking race conditions. The network itself is capable of much higher throughputs over all transacting accounts.

In order to improve your personal TPS, you need to employ more than one transacting account, so that you can issue transactions in parallel. See [Channels doc](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/channels.html), [this question](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/609/how-does-using-channels-increase-transaction-volume), or [my article](https://www.lumenauts.com/blog/boosting-tps-with-stellar-channels).

Comment: But that doesn't change the hard limit that there's `100` tx per ledger. It doesn't matter now many channels I have my transactions will still be limited by that cap. Or anyone's for that matter.

Comment: Edit: Yes, sorry. I read your question right after waking (pre coffee) assumed you were talking about TPS. I seem to recall reading that the ledger size limit is arbitrary and can be increased, but I don't have a source for this.

Comment: I can confirm that. The issue is the fact that we can't do that on the public network without all the network coming to a consensus on that.